# keras - Cannot Save the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I implemented RCAN [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02758.pdf] to keras and trained model.

After that, I tried to save the model as usual, but suddenly it outputs error and doesn't save model .

My whole Code is here :

https://github.com/moonchildz/RCAN-keras/blob/master/rca_keras.py

here is the error message:

```
File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/eps/venv/rca_keras.py", line 97, in <module>
rcan.save(route_save)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1152, in save
save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 449, in save_wrapper
save_function(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 541, in save_model
_serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 129, in _serialize_model
model_config['config'] = model.get_config()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 950, in get_config
return copy.deepcopy(config)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
append(deepcopy(a, memo))
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
state = deepcopy(state, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
state = deepcopy(state, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
state = deepcopy(state, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
rv = reductor(4)

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I have searched other issues and it seems that the problem is that I used Lambda function, but it worked well at my other model.

Can somebody tell me why this happens and what I should do ?

My saving code is :

```
route_save = route + 'rcan.hdf5'

... (Build Model and Nets/ train model ) 

mymodel.save(route_save)
```

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet or github link of your model, so I can see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Please, add the custom layer implementation, so we can help you better.

Comment: https://github.com/moonchildz/RCAN-keras/blob/master/rca_keras.py

Comment: I added github link. Thanks for advice

Comment: Several workarounds are provided for the above error in this issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8343. Thanks!